# Redirect Output to Message r

Tags: r, knitr, fread

Is it possible to capture output that is printed by a function and instead output it via `message`? I am running a report using `knitr` that deals with very large tables (millions of rows) and I have `message` statements in the code so I can have an idea of where I am. This works fine as I simply set the global chunk option to `message = F` and I can see the message in the console and it does not show up in the final `pdf`. However, I use `fread` to read the data from a file, and the `showProgress` option does not print a message! Setting the chunk option to `results='hide'` prevents the progress from being printed to the final document, but it also prevents me from seeing it at all, so that is unhelpful. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: As far as im aware, youll have to go chunk by chunk and set the warnings, messages, echo, etc manually. Would avoid the global initial setting youve done.

Comment: @InfiniteFlashChess My issue is not with the global settings, those are just to say that generally messages are printed to console and not into the final document. My problem is that I do not know a way to print normal `r` output to the console and _not_ to the document.